I have a problem with a dependency that cannot be found in Android Studio
I have an Android app that uses this dependency:
net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.7.
It can't be found no matter the version or repository I use; I always get this error:

"Failed to resolve:
net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.7."

I changed the version of the dependencies, updated the SDK, and called all repositories, but to no avail.
P.S.: I am a complete beginner in mobile apps.

That library has not been updated in many years. It was published on JCenter, which was discontinued a month or so ago.
The best solution with an obsolete library like this is to stop using it.
Alternatively, you could fork that GitHub repo and build the library yourself, publishing it somewhere that you could use it (e.g., Maven Local/mavenLocal()).

FWIW, I wrote more about this situation in my blog.
